# How to generate multiple notifications

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I read all the answers but I couldn't find the right answer. All I need Is to generate five notifications when the special dates (which is stored in my Database) come. 
I won't paste my code here because it is a lot and it's doesn't work, but this is the tutorial I used. http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/#comment-17214. The problem is that in this tutorial is shown how to generate only one notification and after the phone is rebooted the notifications don't come.
I will be very thankful if someone helps me :)

Comment: Follow [Alarm Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) . `setExact` ` API level 19` or `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` ` API level 23`. Use `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED. to reset the alarm.